# Downvoting costs one reputation point

Tags: support, status-bydesign, answers, down-votes, reputation

Today I downvoted an answer and flagged it, too. Now I get negative scores. Presumably, because I wrote a comment on a bad answer, which is downvoted by others too.
Although, I do not care too much about my score, I am interested in understanding the motivation for the negative scores. Is it a bug?

Comment: I don't imagine there would be any bug that could cause negative scores.

Comment: Thanks Kyle Kenos. So I remove the tag "bug". Do you have any alternative explanation?

Comment: Do you know that downvoting an answer always costs 1 rep. point?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238)* (Über Meta), sub section *"You lose reputation when"*, 4th bullet point.

Comment: As for the motivation, the [downvote privilege page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down) puts it succinctly: "Voting down answers is not something we want you to take lightly, so it is not free".

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, after reading your comment above, I wonder if anyone has pointed out that voting down is effectively (or relatively) free for higher rep users. It wouldn't surprise me if it has been suggested (and maybe even discussed) to 'tax' downvotes more heavily from the 'rich' (reputation wise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you down voted an answer then you lose 1 reputation point, which is only viewable to you. Since I can't see this on your own [reputation page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/159486/semoi?tab=reputation) I'm guessing that's what happened. You will probably be able to see it on that page though (and any other reputation change history of yours).

You can't lose/gain reputation for comments in any way.